# (Godot Engine) Fill an 2D Polygon with Tilemap tiles

Tags: godot, gdscript

I have an issue in the Godot Engine that I can't figure it out:
How could it be possible (in code) to fill an Polygon2D area with tiles?
I have tried to get point positions. Iterate through line's vertex using 2D for loops, and I just can't wrap my head around this.

[image: Polygon2D plus TileMap with tiles on the perimeter of the polygon]

*This is an mockup of the result I am expecting*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solution, with a little "hacky" part, but we will get to that.

---

### Iterate over the Segments of the Polygon

First, the idea is to iterate over the segments that make up the polygon. To do that, let us use an `index` in the range from `0` to the number of points in the polygon.

We get the point with that `index` and the point at `index - 1` to be the ends of our segment. *Note that the index `-1` will give us the last point.*

```
for index in range(0, polygon.polygon.size()):
    var segment_start = polygon.polygon[index - 1]
    var segment_end = polygon.polygon[index]
```

We need to work in tile map coordinates. So let us convert them, for that I'll have a custom function `polygon_to_map`, to which we will come back later.

```
for index in range(0, polygon.polygon.size()):
    var segment_start = polygon_to_map(polygon.polygon[index - 1])
    var segment_end = polygon_to_map(polygon.polygon[index])
```

Then we need to get the cells that make up that segment. Again, another custom function `segment` will handle that. We can iterate over the cells, and set them on the tile map:

```
for index in range(0, polygon.polygon.size()):
    var segment_start = polygon_to_map(polygon.polygon[index - 1])
    var segment_end = polygon_to_map(polygon.polygon[index])
    var cells = segment(segment_start, segment_end)
    for cell in cells:
        tile_map.set_cell(celle.x, cell.y, 0)
```

I'm setting tile `0`, you set what makes sense for you.

---

**Coordinate conversion**

The tile map has a handy `world_to_map` function that we can use to convert, meaning we can implement our custom function `polygon_to_map` simply like this:

```
func polygon_to_map(vector:Vector2) -> Vector2:
    return tile_map.world_to_map(vector)
```

However, that would always return integer coordinates. As a consequence we lose information for our `segment` function. Instead I will implement it using `cell_size`:

```
func polygon_to_map(vector:Vector2) -> Vector2:
    return vector/tile_map.cell_size
```

---

### Iterate over the Cells of the Segment

We have to define our `segment` function…

```
func segment(start:Vector2, end:Vector2) -> Array:
    # ???
```

To do this, I'll use the "Fast Voxel Traversal Algorithm". *Other line drawing algorithms would work, I'm fond of this one.*

I often find the explanations of "Fast Voxel Traversal Algorithm" a little hard to parse, instead let us deduce it.

We want to work with the segment in parametric terms. Let us start with traversed length as parameter. If the traversed length is `0`, we are at `start`. If the traversed length is the length of the segment, we are at `end`. Using the traversed length along the segment we can pick any cell along the segment.

In fact, we are defining that the points that make up the segments are of the form:

```
point = start + direction_of_the_segment * traversed_length
```

*Look, everything we will be talking here is about the segment, let us call that variable simply `direction`, ok?*

```
point = start + direction * traversed_length
```

Alright, I said we will be picking cells with `traversed_length`, so we will have a loop, something like this:

```
func segment(start:Vector2, end:Vector2) -> Array:
    var length = start.distance_to(end)     # (end - start).length()
    var direction = start.direction_to(end) # (end - start).normalized()
    var traversed_length = 0
    while traversed_length < length:
        var cell = start + direction * traversed_length
        # something that increments traversed_length and other stuff
```

Now, the trick is to know how much we have to traverse until we reach the next integer value along the x axis, and how much until the next integer value along the y axis.

For now, let us say we have a function `next2` that gives the next value along the axis, according to the direction:

```
var next = next2(start, direction)
```

*We will talk about the details of `next2` later.*

Now, we will need to compute what is the length we need to traverse until we reach the next value. Let us use our equation form before:

```
point = start + direction * traversed_length
```

But now, the point will be the next after start, and the length is what we are looking for

```
next = start + direction * length_to_next

=>

next - start = direction * length_to_next

=>

(next - start) / direction = length_to_next
```

Thus:

```
var length_to_next = (next - start)/direction
```

Let us update our code (remember that we have to update `length_to_next` when we increment `traversed_length`):

```
func segment(start:Vector2, end:Vector2) -> Array:
    var length = start.distance_to(end)     # (end - start).length()
    var direction = start.direction_to(end) # (end - start).normalized()
    var next = next2(start, direction)
    var length_to_next = div2(next - start, direction)
    var traversed_length = 0
    while traversed_length < length:
        var cell = start + direction * traversed_length
        if length_to_next.x < length_to_next.y:
            traversed_length += length_to_next.x
            length_to_next.x = # ??
            length_to_next.y -= length_to_next.x
        else:
            traversed_length += length_to_next.y
            length_to_next.x -= length_to_next.y
            length_to_next.y = # ??
```

What is that `div2`? Ah, right, we have it because zero divided by zero. This happens when the segment is perfectly vertical or horizontal. The value we want in that case is `INF`, so it is never smaller and the code does not enter on that branch. To do that, you can define this:

```
func div2(numerator:Vector2, denominator:Vector2) -> Vector2:
    return Vector2(div(numerator.x, denominator.x), div(numerator.y, denominator.y))

func div(numerator:float, denominator:float) -> float:
    return numerator / denominator if denominator != 0 else INF
```

Ok, we have another problem. If we traversed to the next position on x, for example, what is the length to the next position of x (And the same for y)?

Back to our equation, this time we assume `start` is 0:

```
point = start + direction * length_between

=> 

point = direction * length_between

=> 

point/direction = length_between
```

What should point be? Well, if we started at 0, and advanced in the direction of direction to the next integer… That point is a vector with `-1`, `0` or `1` on its components, according to the direction of the segment. That is the `sign` of the direction.

Thus, we have (we don't need `div2` this time):

```
var direction_sign = direction.sign()
var length_between = direction_sign/direction
```

Update our code:

```
func segment(start:Vector2, end:Vector2) -> Array:
    var length = start.distance_to(end)     # (end - start).length()
    var direction = start.direction_to(end) # (end - start).normalized()
    var direction_sign = direction.sign()
    var next = next2(start, direction)
    var length_to_next = div2(next - start, direction)
    var length_between = direction_sign/direction
    var traversed_length = 0
    while traversed_length < length:
        var cell = start + direction * traversed_length
        if length_to_next.x < length_to_next.y:
            traversed_length += length_to_next.x
            length_to_next.x = length_between.x
            length_to_next.y -= length_to_next.x
        else:
            traversed_length += length_to_next.y
            length_to_next.x -= length_to_next.y
            length_to_next.y = length_between.y
```

Ah, right, we should return. Let us build a result array, populate it and return it:

```
func segment(start:Vector2, end:Vector2) -> Array:
    var length = start.distance_to(end)     # (end - start).length()
    var direction = start.direction_to(end) # (end - start).normalized()
    var direction_sign = direction.sign()
    var next = next2(start, direction)
    var length_to_next = div2(next - start, direction)
    var length_between = direction_sign/direction
    var traversed_length = 0
    var result = []
    result.append(start)
    while traversed_length < length:
        if length_to_next.x < length_to_next.y:
            traversed_length += length_to_next.x
            length_to_next.x = length_between.x
            length_to_next.y -= length_to_next.x
        else:
            traversed_length += length_to_next.y
            length_to_next.x -= length_to_next.y
            length_to_next.y = length_between.y
        result.append(start + direction * traversed_length)
    return result
```

Does this work? Yes, this works. Is this "Fast Voxel Traversal Algorithm"? Not exactly. Let us call it the "Slow Voxel Traversal Algorithm" for future reference (also because from here it is *mostly* optimizations).

---

Let us start by keeping a `current` vector (this will allow us to do the next refactor):

```
func segment(start:Vector2, end:Vector2) -> Array:
    var length = start.distance_to(end)     # (end - start).length()
    var direction = start.direction_to(end) # (end - start).normalized()
    var direction_sign = direction.sign()
    var next = next2(start, direction)
    var length_to_next = div2(next - start, direction)
    var length_between = direction_sign/direction
    var traversed_length = 0
    var result = []
    var current = start
    while traversed_length < length:
        if length_to_next.x < length_to_next.y:
            current += direction * length_to_next.x
            traversed_length += length_to_next.x
            length_to_next.x = length_between.x
            length_to_next.y -= length_to_next.x
        else:
            current += direction * length_to_next.y
            traversed_length += length_to_next.y
            length_to_next.x -= length_to_next.y
            length_to_next.y = length_between.y
        result.append(current)
    return result
```

*In my tests, this version sometimes skips tiles.*

Now, that we have `current`, having `traversed_length` is less vital. To remove it, we will accumulate length, never subtract (this way we are doing less each cycle):

```
func segment(start:Vector2, end:Vector2) -> Array:
    var length = start.distance_to(end)     # (end - start).length()
    var direction = start.direction_to(end) # (end - start).normalized()
    var direction_sign = direction.sign()
    var next = next2(start, direction)
    var length_to_next = div2(next - start, direction)
    var length_between = direction_sign/direction
    var result = []
    var current = start
    result.append(current)
    while length_to_next.x < length or length_to_next.y < length:
        if length_to_next.x < length_to_next.y:
            current.x += direction_sign.x
            length_to_next.x += length_between.x
        else:
            current.y += direction_sign.y
            length_to_next.y += length_between.y
        result.append(current)
    return result
```

*This kind of works. Something got messed up with the rounding. See the "hacky" part.*

Let us scale lengths down by `length` (as if our original parameter was from 0 to 1). We can also get rid of `direction`, and while we are at it, inline `next`. By doing this we don't need the square root. Also we don't need `div2` anymore.

```
func segment(start:Vector2, end:Vector2) -> Array:
    var difference = end - start
    var direction_sign = difference.sign()
    var length_to_next = (next2(start, direction_sign) - start)/difference
    var length_between = direction_sign/difference
    var result = []
    var current = start
    result.append(current)
    while length_to_next.x < 1 or length_to_next.y < 1:
        if length_to_next.x < length_to_next.y:
            current.x += direction_sign.x
            length_to_next.x += length_between.x
        else:
            current.y += direction_sign.y
            length_to_next.y += length_between.y
        result.append(current)
    return result
```

*If you prefer a nomenclature closer to the paper "Fast Voxel Traversal Algorithm", then rename `length_between` to `tDelta`, `length_to_next` to `tMax`, and `direction_sign` to `step`. Another difference is that I'm assuming that the grid size is `1`.*

---

**On `next` and the "hacky" part**

We need a `next2` function, it looks like this:

```
func next2(vector:Vector2, direction:Vector2) -> Vector2:
    return Vector2(next(vector.x, direction.x), next(vector.y, direction.y))
```

And a `next` function. For the "Slow Voxel Traversal Algorithm", it is like this:

```
func next(value:float, direction:float) -> float:
    if direction > 0:
        return max(ceil(value), floor(value + 1.0))

    return min(floor(value), ceil(value - 1.0))
```

What is going on there? Well, if `value` is not integer, then `ceil` or `floor` depending on `direction` would suffice. However, if `value` is integer, we want to add or subtract `1`. Written the way it is written, I don't need to check if the value is an integer.

Note, however, I said that is for "Slow Voxel Traversal Algorithm". For the "Fast Voxel Traversal Algorithm" I found experimentally that it should be:

```
func next(value:float, direction:float) -> float:
    if direction > 0:
        return max(ceil(value), floor(value + 1.0))

    return floor(value)
```

And after distancing myself form the problem I found a better version:

```
func next(value:float, direction:float) -> float:
    return floor(value) + clamp(sign(direction), 0, 1)
```

*I'm not sure why that is the case. However, as far as I can tell, it is because we are incrementing by `direction_sign`.*

Comment: Thank you so much for such an elaborate answer. And most of all, thank you for providing me material to learn so many things instead of just copy/pasting information. I can't express how grateful I am.