# Godot - Change tiles within an area

Tags: godot, gdscript

I'm trying to make it so if a function is called an area covered by a Collisionshape2D gets its tiles removed in a TileMap node. My problem is the area deleted doesn't match the Collisionshape2D's. Any insight is appreciated! Thank you.

My code:

```
func changeArea(collionshape):
    var corridorTile = $CorridorTiles
    var rect = Rect2(collionshape.position, collionshape.shape.extents*2)
    var topleft = corridorTile.world_to_map(rect.position)
    var bottomright = corridorTile.world_to_map(rect.end)
    for x in range(topleft.x, bottomright.x):
        for y in range(topleft.y, bottomright.y):
            corridorTile.set_cell(x, y, -1)
```

---

Edit1*

Upon changing the code to:

```
func changeCorridorTile(collionshape):
    var corridorTile = $CorridorTiles
    var extents:Vector2 = collionshape.shape.extents
    var topleft = corridorTile.world_to_map(collionshape.position - extents)
    var bottomright = corridorTile.world_to_map(collionshape.position + extents)
    for x in range(topleft.x, bottomright.x):
        for y in range(topleft.y, bottomright.y):
            corridorTile.set_cell(x, y, -1)
    corridorTile.update_bitmask_region()
```

The cells in the `tileMap` which the `collisionShape2D` area covers get deleted. And I update them using .bitmask_region() method.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I notice, from the top of my head: The `Rect2` position is a corner, but the `CollisionShape` position is the center.

You would have to do it like this:

```
var extents:Vector2 = collionshape.shape.extents
var rect := Rect2(collionshape.position - extents, extents * 2)
```

Now, on a second look, you don't need the `Rect2` at all:

```
var extents:Vector2 = collionshape.shape.extents
var topleft = corridorTile.world_to_map(collionshape.position - extents)
var bottomright = corridorTile.world_to_map(collionshape.position + extents)
```

One more thing: I believe that is in local space of the parent of the `CollisionShape2D` (an `Area2D`, I guess). So, if that is not working, it might be because you need to do it in global space. Hopefully you don't have any rotation (which would just mess the whole thing up) or scaling, so that would only be a matter of using `global_position`.

---

Addendum: I forgot something, `world_to_map` does not take global coordinates. Try this instead (assuming no rotation or scaling):

```
var extents:Vector2 = collionshape.shape.extents
var position := corridorTile.to_local(collionshape.global_position)
var topleft = corridorTile.world_to_map(position - extents)
var bottomright = corridorTile.world_to_map(position  + extents)
```

Comment: It's exactly as you said, I over complicated it by trying to use a Rect2 and also I didn't consider the fact that the area's position was in the center. using a vector2 has deleted the cells around the CollisionShape2D.  I did my code ever so slightly different from the one in your addendum, correct me if I'm wrong but world_to_map should give the global position of collisionShape2D so `corridorTile.world_to_map(collionshape.position -/+ extents)` worked just fine, Thank you for helping me out!

Comment: @WannabeDev `world_to_map` gives you the position in the `TileMap`. It takes local position, see [`world_to_map`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_tilemap.html#class-tilemap-method-world-to-map) -  I assume in your case the local coordinates of the `CollisionShape2D` match the `TileMap` - It is pretty much dividing by the cell size and rounding ([source](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/3.3/scene/2d/tile_map.cpp#L1622)). See also [(Godot Engine) Fill an 2D Polygon with Tilemap tiles](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67161901/402022).

Comment: I just checked and, the `CollisionShape2D` position did match the `TileMap` as you said.  I'll put this one my notes in case I need to manipulate tile maps using `world_to_map` in the future